# Invalid HTTP Header in a response

Tags: http, web, server, backend, httpbackend

I have some URL and make a request to that URL but a response is invalid. I checked requests in Chrome dev tools and Chrome didn't find something wrong. I make a request in Postman but I receive "Parse Error: There seems to be an invalid character in response header key or value". Also I make requests in Axios in Node.js and I receive an error again.

After all, I checked request in chrome dev tools again and then I saw that:

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: close
Date: Wed, 30 Jun 2021 12:05:28 GMT
Server: Boa/0.94.14rc21
```

There are parsed headers from the response and I clicked on a "View source" and saw that:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 30 Jun 2021 12:05:28 GMT
Server: Boa/0.94.14rc21
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: close
<Content-Type:text/html>
```

Is it normal or I should receive content-type without angle brackets? Maybe it's documented somewhere as a standart?

UPD. I made requests to a dashboard of Yeastar TG200

UPD 2. Also I made POST-requests and I received valid content-type in response headers without angle brackets

Comment: The angle brackets around that last line shouldn't be there. I wonder where that is from.

Comment: I made requests to the web-dashboard of Yeastar TG200. It's a GSM-gateway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angle brackets in a field name are definitively invalid (see https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#rule.token.separators).